# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Backbone.Wreqr.radio')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

I am using Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0, Backbone.js 1.3.3, MarionetteJS (Backbone.Marionette) v2.4.5,  Underscore.js 1.8.3.

My `application.js` file is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require lib/underscore
//= require lib/backbone
//= require lib/marionette
//= require backbone/app
```

I am following the tutorial from `backbonerails.com`.
I am at the beginning of the chapter 5 and the app is empty, no footer, no header no main content.

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Backbone.Wreqr.radio')
_initChannel — marionette.self-5755e16504f179d152ad666130d554d6925cca98e4374dbad360dc6b42b17d74.js:3232
constructor — marionette.self-5755e16504f179d152ad666130d554d6925cca98e4374dbad360dc6b42b17d74.js:3100
(anonymous function) — app.self-a30509b2e8139de6bc6c843d616c92384df06b065083ad664d54a1bfa1e59250.js:4
(anonymous function) — app.self-a30509b2e8139de6bc6c843d616c92384df06b065083ad664d54a1bfa1e59250.js:16
global code — app.self-a30509b2e8139de6bc6c843d616c92384df06b065083ad664d54a1bfa1e59250.js:18
```

And this error, which I am assuming that is a consequence of the previous one:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Demo
(anonymous function) — localhost:24
fire — jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:3233
fireWith — jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:3363
ready — jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:3583
completed — jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js:3618
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue ?